# IOS ARKit Swift how can I get distance between me and a SCNNode when I move

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have an issue with ARkit, I use ARWorldTrackingConfiguration and when I have a SCNNode one meter away from me, when I use Iphone X and move to the SCNNode, the Z position of my camera SCNNode updates and I know that I am closer to the node, but with other Iphones (Iphone 8) I don't get an update to Z position.

Also with GPS even with kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation I don't have accuracy.

How can I know that I am closer to the SCNNode?? Thank you

Comment: I have done getting distance every frame from iPad and it works fine. Can you show us your code.

Comment: self.myARsceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[0].position for the position of my node and self.myARsceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes[1].position for the position of my camera, and I remind you that in I phone X it works perfect and I can see the update in the position

Comment: Now i am not sure with `childNodes[1]` as camera. This gives your current device camera position `sceneView.pointOfView?.worldPosition`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer although I have the same problem, no matter how much I move the phone the sceneView.pointOfView?.worldPosition is always SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0) in Iphone 8 but in Iphone X it gets updated

Comment: Now i only have iPhone X and iPad Pro so i cant test it. But in simple theory it should always update the position of camera

Comment: I think this is not relevant for camera but i used `node.presentation.worldPosition` to get nodes position (it was a child of another node) and `convertPosition(node, to: sceneView.scene.rootNode)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am almost sure that it's a device issue, I will test to more devices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

implementing `ARSCNViewDelegate` in your ViewController, it will be called the `renderer:updateAtTime` callback once per frame.
Inside this function you can get the position of your camera relative to the real world calling `sceneView.session.currentFrame.camera.transform` which is a `simd_float4x4`. You can access the current position of your camera with `transform.columns.3` and peeking the x,y,z field from it. With these coordinates you can calculate the distance, such the Euclidean distance with these functions

```
func distanceTravelled(xDist:Float, yDist:Float, zDist:Float) -> Float{
    return sqrt((xDist*xDist)+(yDist*yDist)+(zDist*zDist))
}

func distanceTravelled(between v1:SCNVector3,and v2:SCNVector3) -> Float{

    let xDist = v1.x - v2.x
    let yDist = v1.y - v2.y
    let zDist = v1.z - v2.z

    return distanceTravelled(xDist: xDist, yDist: yDist, zDist: zDist)
}
```

Remember to convert the coordinates of the nodes to worldCoordinates -> `node.worldPosition` with node an instance of `SCNNode`